# Scheduling based problem

Tags: mathematics, packing

Can you place these numbers into 5 rows of 4 such that each row totals 20?

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.

> 1,5,6,8
>  2,4,6,8
>  3,4,5,8
>  4,4,5,7
>  5,5,5,5

Method:

> Started from the bigger numbers, and partitioned into 5 parts of 20: {8,8,4}, {8,7,5} and so on.
>
>  Then swapped a big number with two smaller ones (with the same sum) on another row until I had 4 numbers on each row.

With some fiddling, it's also possible to get all the columns to add up to 25:

> 1,8,6,5
>  5,4,7,4
>  5,5,5,5
>  6,4,2,8
>  8,4,5,3

And here's a magic square (with duplicates, unavoidably) followed by a row of fives:

> 1,6,8,5
>  5,7,4,4
>  8,5,4,3
>  6,2,4,8
>  5,5,5,5

And finally:

> ```
>  4 4 8 4
>  8 5 4 3
>  1 5 6 8
>  7 6 2 5
>  5 5 5 5
> ```
>
> This has
>  * 20 on all 5 rows
>  * 20 on all 4 long diagonals
>  * 25 in all 4 columns
>  * a magic square on the first 4 rows

Comment: I'm late ! But I have differents rows :D

Comment: I like the way you went on to challenge yourself by finding solutions to your own proposed questions.

Comment: @5202456 Thanks! The original solution seemed to leave an awful lot of "wiggle room" in the pattern, so I wanted to see what I could do with it. I added one more "extra magical" solution after your comment; hopefully I didn't make any mistakes, as the numbers are starting to bounce around in my eyes :-)

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party and cannot beat the excellent answer from @Bass.

I worked out the number of distinct solutions bearing in mind they can be further permuted by ordering each row and the row sequence. I found

> 16 distinct solutions

I did this by first finding all the sets of four digits which sum to 20.

> There are 17 sets of digits
>
> ```
>   1  3  8  8
>   1  4  7  8
>   1  5  6  8
>   1  6  6  7
>   2  3  7  8
>   2  4  6  8
>   2  5  5  8
>   2  5  6  7
>   3  4  5  8
>   3  4  6  7
>   3  5  5  7
>   3  5  6  6
>   4  4  4  8
>   4  4  5  7
>   4  4  6  6
>   4  5  5  6
>   5  5  5  5
> ```

I then permuted them for each row so that each digit is used the right number of times.

> These are the 16 solutions
>
> ```
>  1  3  8  8     1  3  8  8     1  3  8  8     1  3  8  8
>  2  4  6  8     2  5  5  8     2  5  5  8     2  5  6  7
>  4  4  5  7     4  4  5  7     4  4  5  7     4  4  4  8
>  4  5  5  6     4  4  6  6     4  5  5  6     4  5  5  6
>  5  5  5  5     5  5  5  5     4  5  5  6     5  5  5  5
>
>  1  4  7  8     1  4  7  8     1  4  7  8     1  4  7  8
>  2  4  6  8     2  5  5  8     2  5  5  8     2  5  5  8
>  3  4  5  8     3  4  5  8     3  4  5  8     3  5  6  6
>  4  5  5  6     4  4  6  6     4  5  5  6     4  4  4  8
>  5  5  5  5     5  5  5  5     4  5  5  6     5  5  5  5
>
>  1  5  6  8     1  5  6  8     1  5  6  8     1  5  6  8
>  2  3  7  8     2  4  6  8     2  4  6  8     2  5  5  8
>  4  4  4  8     3  4  5  8     3  5  5  7     3  4  5  8
>  4  5  5  6     4  4  5  7     4  4  4  8     4  4  5  7
>  5  5  5  5     5  5  5  5     5  5  5  5     4  5  5  6
>
>  1  5  6  8     1  5  6  8     1  5  6  8     1  6  6  7
>  2  5  5  8     2  5  5  8     2  5  6  7     2  5  5  8
>  3  4  6  7     3  5  5  7     3  4  5  8     3  4  5  8
>  4  4  4  8     4  4  4  8     4  4  4  8     4  4  4  8
>  5  5  5  5     4  5  5  6     5  5  5  5     5  5  5  5
> ```

Method:

> A computer program written in C.

Comment: Nice! FYI I generated the puzzle from row 2 column 4.

Answer (score 3):

This one works

> 7 3 5 5 
>  8 2 5 5 
>  6 4 5 5 
>  8 6 1 5 
>  8 4 4 4

Method :

> Write randomly the numbers on a piece of paper during 5 min until the solution appears magically.